# RSpec 3: Simple validates_uniqueness_of Failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, rspec, factory-bot

I am trying to test the uniqueness validation on a model that won't pass. I have an identical validation test on another model that passes but I don't understand what I am missing on this.

I have searched around the forum and tried a few things but still no pass. I'm sure there is something small and significant to learn here!

Here's my code..

**factories.rb**

```
FactoryGirl.define do

    factory :quote do
        sequence (:content) { |x| "Dust is dirty word number #{x}!" }
        reference "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Einstein"
        author_id 1
    end

end
```

**quote_spec.rb**

```
require 'rails_helper'
require 'shoulda/matchers'

RSpec.describe Quote, :type => :model do
    quote = FactoryGirl.build(:quote)

  it { expect(quote).to belong_to(:author) }

    describe "attributes" do

        it "saves attributes" do
            quote.save!
            expect(quote).to be_valid
        end

        it "stores author id" do
            expect(quote[:author_id]).to eq(1)
        end
  end


    context "validations" do
        it { expect(quote).to validate_presence_of   :content }
        it { expect(quote).to validate_uniqueness_of :content, message: "That's been said before!" }
    end

end
```

**quote.rb**

```
class Quote < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :author, inverse_of: :quote
    validates :content, :reference, presence: :true
    validates_uniqueness_of :content, message: "That's been said before!"
end
```

**failure**

```
Quote
  should belong to author
  attributes
    saves attributes
    stores author id
  validations
    should require content to be set
    example at ./spec/models/quote_spec.rb:24 (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

  1) Quote validations 
     Failure/Error: it { expect(quote).to validate_uniqueness_of :content, message: "That's been said before!" }
     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
     # ./spec/models/quote_spec.rb:24:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: Hey Anthony, failure is now up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right, just a small syntax issue to fix:

```
it { is_expected.to validate_uniqueness_of(:content).with_message("That's been said before!") }
```

Comment: Thanks Anthony. Worked great. I haven't used the is_expected method yet so this was a good introduction.